# How to find the cosine similarity between 2 dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cosine-similarity

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1:
font_label |font_size | len_words |letter_per_words |text_area_ratio | image_area   | Effectiveness |
    1          11           7          9.714286          0.046231         310200    |    20.2
    2          10.5         8           11               0.0399           310150         19.2
    1          11.5         9           10               0.040            310100         21.2
```

```
df2:

font_label |font_size | len_words |letter_per_words |text_area_ratio | image_area   | Effectiveness |
    1          12           8          10.5              0.0399           310100    |    21
```

I was trying to write a function in which df2 is passed and the output should be a row from df1 which
is the closest match based on cosine similarity, and the output row(i.e selected row from df1) should have the Effectiveness column greater than Effectiveness column in df2.

I tried to do the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

X = cosine_similarity(df1)
y = cosine_similarity(df2)
```

After this i have no idea how to proceed to get the output.

Expected Output:

```
When df2 is passed to the function my expected output is:

font_label |font_size | len_words |letter_per_words |text_area_ratio | image_area   | Effectiveness |
    1          11.5         9           10               0.040            310100         21.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def get_closest_row(df1, df2):

    # Get the cosine similarity
    cos_sim = cosine_similarity(df1.drop(columns=['Effectiveness']), df2.drop(columns=['Effectiveness']))

    # Get the index of the maximum value in the cosine similarity
    index = np.argmax(cos_sim)

    # Get the row from df1 with the maximum cosine similarity
    row = df1.iloc[index]

    # Return the row
    return row
```

Then, if one applies to `df1` and `df2`, one gets the following

```
df_new = get_closest_row(df1, df2)

[Out]:

font_label               1.00
font_size               11.50
len_words                9.00
letter_per_words        10.00
text_area_ratio          0.04
image_area          310100.00
Effectiveness           21.20
Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

However, as one wants a dataframe, one will have to convert it with [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). In order to end up with the desired output, one will have to transpose it, so one passses `.T`

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_new).T

[Out]:

   font_label  font_size  len_words  ...  text_area_ratio  image_area  Effectiveness
2         1.0       11.5        9.0  ...             0.04    310100.0           21.2
```

A one liner would be as follows

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df1.iloc[np.argmax(cosine_similarity(df1.drop(columns=['Effectiveness']), df2.drop(columns=['Effectiveness'])))]).T

[Out]:

   font_label  font_size  len_words  ...  text_area_ratio  image_area  Effectiveness
2         1.0       11.5        9.0  ...             0.04    310100.0           21.2
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. The final output(df_new)  "Effectiveness" column should always be greater than the df2.  Even if the match is very closest but the Effectiveness value is less the function should select the next closest record. In the above example it worked fine., but it may not be the case all the time.  @Gonçalo Peres where can i include a condition like this in the code?

Comment: @Sasi the most intuitive way would be to adjust the function `get_closest_row` by adding a check to validate if it is greater than the Effectiveness in `df2`. Something like `if row['Effectiveness'] > df2['Effectiveness'].values[0]: return row else: [NEXT STEPS]`. And adjust the next steps accordingly.